# My wardrobe isn't showing up in chat!

Tags: support, chat

My hats aren't showing up in chat!

[image]

My self-image next to my chatbox has my full regalia, but the gravatar next to my posted messages has a measly two hats!  It's not a cache delay because it already put on my current hat.  It is using an outdated version of my gravatar and adding my current hat to that.

Do I have too much bling for chat?

Comment: I don't know exactly how Winterbash on chat works, but I don't think the hat choice is cached along with your profile. Your profile only gets updated from the parent site every so often. The script that adds the hats probably isn't cached as heavily, and probably fetches from a completely different source.

Comment: I *think* this is [tag:status-bydesign] due to the caching, but I won't be 100% sure until I look at the code later (or balpha decides to be bad at vacation, as we are wont to) -- anyway, I also forced a refresh of your chat profile.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Winter Bash. As you said yourself, the hat is correct.

Comment: @balpha whoops, don't blame the OP, it's my fault.

Comment: @balpha I don't care too much about this question, but it isn't a dupe of that - in this case, the system had _already_ used a newer version of my gravatar, then went back to an _older_ one and put my newest hat on a _previous_ version of my gravatar that it had already moved on from.  But whatever.

Comment: And, on top of that, it updated my gravatar for one part of chat and not the other.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand, but I'll reopen the question. Can you edit the question to clarify what exactly happened?